# If I am not getting feeback for my questions, can I just post the same question another day?

Tags: discussion, support, etiquette, best-practices

I posted a thread a few days ago about the explanation of a proof.  I arranged the thread by providing little fragments of the proof, getting feeback on that specific fragment and then posting the remaining fragments. I couldn't fully post the whole proof because I wasn't getting enough feedback, so I am just wondering if I can re-post the same question, but now with the complete proof.

Comment: If you didn't get any answers, a better option is to edit the original version of your question. Reposting (even with updates) is frowned upon. That edit also "bumps" your question to the front page of active posts.

Comment: See also [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question) and other discussions [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478).

Comment: This one seems to be almost a duplicate: [Can I ask the same question twice?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6714/can-i-ask-the-same-question-twice)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can add a bounty to your question to attract users to it. You can also edit your original post.

Comment: I want to caution that I would use editing sparingly. I personally am annoyed when I see a post repeatedly edited just to garner more attention (it's borderline when the editing is "excessively frequent" but there are improvements).