# Is it allowed to repost?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

If I have a question no one answered or comment to ever, since 2 months. Is it allowed to delete it and repost it, or is this abuse?

Comment: See also: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478) and [other posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478).

Comment: This past discussions seem to be about the same topic (possibly you can find also other related threads):
[Can I ask the same question twice?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6714),
[If I am not getting feedback for my questions, can I just post the same question another day?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23681),
[Is double posting allowed if a question is not answered after some time?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26282), [Looking for An Answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30003).

Comment: Thanks. I always searched for 'repost', so I didn't find them.

Comment: Thanks for asking, @mag. I appreciate your effort to check it out here, first!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. You are not allowed to do that.

Comment: However, you are allowed to edit the question to make improvements.  A side-effect of that is: the question will appear on the Active Questions list.  But of course do not keep doing this multiple times.  Some questions are never answered.

Comment: Also you can post a bounty.