# Can I repost any old question of mine?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I had asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772820/prove-sylvester-gallai-theorem-using-combinatorics) a while ago (a month or two). It has two upvotes and $37$ views as of now, thus this question hasn't gone unnoticed. But the question was active only a month ago and I haven't yet received any solutions. Would it be okay for me to repost a question in hope of receiving an answer?

Comment: Worth remarking:  I think the solution provided to the duplicate question you link to is as simple as you are likely to find.  It's a fairly well known result...if a simpler argument were known, I'd expect it to be well known.  Certainly, the accepted solution is the popularly known argument, well worth studying.

Comment: See also: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478) Also [other questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478). In particular, these questions seem close to yours:
[Is it allowed to repost?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31572), [Can I ask the same question twice?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6714), [If I am not getting feedback for my questions, can I just post the same question another day?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23681), ...

Comment: ... [Is double posting allowed if a question is not answered after some time?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26282), [Looking for An Answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30003).

Comment: One thing that I'd like to have articulated is what it means for a proof to be combinatorial but not by induction, yet done at "a high school level."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. It would be very much not okay.

You can offer a bounty, this will bump it to the front page, and offer some additional incentive for people to think about it.

If you have new information, you can also edit that in. Although editing with trivial changes more than once is likely to annoy people, so please be prudent with these sort of things, and edit actual relevant information into the question.

Comment: Thanks, I woud as well have reposted that question without asking on meta and have erred. Also, since offering bounty will attract users with high reputation, would they care to provide solution using high school maths rather than using higher level maths?

Comment: Why do you think it would attract users with high reputation? If your question asks for a specific level of solution, I also don't see why any different answer would be an appropriate answer (it could, provided that a good answer was given to your liking, but even then, it might be debatable).